# Microsoft Graph SSO Azure AD not redirecting user to Login page

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Sorry but I am just learning about Microsoft Graph and I have spent the last 4 hours scouring Google to find my answer and my brain is going to explode so I have resorted to Stack.

I was using a previous method to authenticate a user to Azure AD but it has no more support and I want to switch over to Microsoft Graph. I am able to get the access token but that is as far as I get.

At this point all I want to do send the user to the Microsoft Login page so they can authenticate and be redirected back to my web app. I have read so much I don't know what else I can read. Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction to how to get this accomplished? also where in the world is the documentation for this?

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$tenantId = "***********************************";
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0';
$token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => '***********************************',
        'client_secret' => '***********************************',
        'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.example.com/here'
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$accessToken = $token->access_token;

// Create a new Graph client.
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```

Comment: If you want to log in as a user, don't use the daemon-based client credential flow. It has no user interaction. You should use the auth code flow. Here is a sample:   https://developer.byu.edu/docs/consume-api/use-api/oauth-20/oauth-20-php-sample-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment moved to answer:

As I said in the comments, if you need to log in as a user and authenticate, please don't use a daemon-based **client credential flow** because there is no user interaction with this flow. You should use the [authentication code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), which requires you to log in to the user and obtain the authorization code, and then use the authorization code to redeem the access token.

Sample for your reference：

[OAuth 2.0 PHP Sample Code](https://developer.byu.edu/docs/consume-api/use-api/oauth-20/oauth-20-php-sample-code).

[Authentication and Authorization Using Auth0 in PHP](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authentication-and-authorization-using-auth0-in-php--cms-31134).

[Microsoft Graph Connect Sample for PHP](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/php-connect-sample).

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense. I am going to be needing to use a daemon-based cred for when I start incorporating Teams into my app, but it makes sense about the `Aauth0()`. Thanks for the clarification.